# use first-Child with $(this)

Tags: jquery

`$(this):first-child` is the wrong syntax

I didn't know how to use `first-child` with `$(this)` in a `.each` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find).

**HTML**

```
<div id='myDiv'>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>world</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#myDiv').each(function() {
    alert($(this).find(':first-child').text());
});
```

[jQuery :first-child in .each() loop - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nyuszika7H/eKVxt/)

Comment: wouldn't `$('#myDiv :fist-child')` make more sense? That is, do the search directly, without the inbetween `each`-loop. Not that that would make much sense at all though (all first-children in the subtree of a single div...), but rather `$('.myClass > :first-child')`? (The first child of all objects with class `myClass`)

Comment: @roe The OP said: in an `.each()` loop. I don't see the code anywhere, so I don't know if that loop is needed or not.

Comment: Yeah, I know, you're right, I just figured the OP didn't say much at all, so noting that this might not be what he wants at all could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

you should try

```
$(':first-child', this)
```

see this example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/idegi4/edit)

Comment: Though you posted it before me, my solution is faster, because yours calls `.find()`. Look at the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L170-174).

Comment: Here's a [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context)  (more ops/sec is better). Though it shows small difference, and in some cases, context may be faster, but still, it's a second call.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, but I'm not sure if the order is guaranteed:

```
$(this).children()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume 'this' is not a JQuery object, but a DOM-object, wouldn't this do what you want?

```
this.childNodes[0]
```

This will also return text-nodes, don't know if JQuery does that.

That said, if you only want the first 'div' child child nodes of nodes with `myClass` class, do your `.each` loop differently

```
$(".myClass > div:fist-child").each(function() {...})
```

Comment: It looks like it is a jQuery object. `children()` doesn't return text nodes, but `find()` does.

Comment: @Andrew; he's using `.each`, where `this` is referring to the DOM-object (which is why you need to wrap it like `$(this)` if you want to do JQuery operations on it).